# In BigQuery order by is not not working as same as Tsql

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-order-by

Below query is running smoothly if I remove order by. Any insights why it is not accepting transformed data in order by ?

[image]

Code for your reference:

```
select date(creation_date) , count(*) from bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_links
group by  date(creation_date)
order by  date(creation_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(creation_date), COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_links
GROUP BY DATE(creation_date)
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Adding alias name:

```
SELECT DATE(creation_date) AS crdate, COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_links
GROUP BY crdate
ORDER BY crdate DESC LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Comment: If you add alias name it produces same error again

Comment: SELECT DATE(creation_date) crdate, COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_links
GROUP BY DATE(creation_date)
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: @vignesh updated the answer - accept the answer, if it solves your requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [gcp document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause)

> The ORDER BY clause specifies a column or expression as the sort criterion for the result set. If a query contains aliases in the SELECT clause, those aliases override names in the corresponding FROM clause. The data type of expression must be orderable.

In your query you have set `date(creation_date)` as the  `functional output` but then again in the group by clause you have used the same functional expression instead of using output of function and order by clause also you do the same.

It is better to use ordinals or alias names in group by and order by clause.

`Example using ordinals:`

```
select date(creation_date)  , count(*) from bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_links
group by  1 order by 1;
```

For using aliases names you can refer to @Rathish Kumar B answer.